# Importing locators in puppeteer tests using const

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have an object repository file where I store all the locators. However to improve maintainability and readability, I am now grouping the locators using const. For example:

```
const delivery = {
    DELIVERY_HEADING: "xpath=//div[OOtext()='Delivery']",
    DELIVERY_COUNT: '.bit-deliverylistrow'
};
const operations = {
    SAVE_AUD: '.bit-save-btn',
    SAVE_AUDNAME: "xpath=//*[text()='Audience name']/../input"
};

module.exports = { delivery, operations }
```

In the tests, I am using importing and using them as:

```
const or = require('../TestData/OR');

await page.focus(or.delivery.DELIVERY_HEADING);
await page.type(or.operations.SAVE_AUDNAME,'hello');
```

Is there a way I don't have to refer to the const and directly call the object locators in the test as it is difficult to identify which const has which locator ?

I would like to do `await page.focus(or.DELIVERY_HEADING)`

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread `...` to create a single object.

```
module.exports = { ...delivery, ...operations }
```

Now you can do,

```
await page.focus(or.DELIVERY_HEADING)
```